# Difference between "SAP Fiori apps" and "SAPUI5 application"

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

Could anyone please explain me the difference between *SAP Fiori apps* and *SAPUI5 application*?

[In the document](https://help.sap.com/viewer/a7b390faab1140c087b8926571e942b7/1709.001/en-US/33daedef95454af68903ef1238aa0373.html) which SAP has given to create target mapping, it's mentioned that the application type *SAPUI5 Fiori App* has to be selected only for *SAP Fiori Apps* and not for other *SAPUI5 Applications*.

> You can only use this function for SAP Fiori apps. Do not use this function for other SAPUI5 applications.

Till now I am believing that Fiori is a collection of SAP UI5 applications. If both are the same means why we should not select SAPUI5 Fiori for other UI5 applications.

Please correct me if am wrong and also please clear the confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Fiori** (in SAP context) means several things:

(Some of the infos may reflect a more or less current state of the art and may have been different in the past and may change in future.)

- **Fiori Apps** (or sometimes called SAP standard Fiori Apps) is a set of (several thousand?) Apps developed and offered by SAP. This includes Fiori Apps for various businesses (like retail) or various departments (like HCM) - See [SAP Fiori App Reference Library](https://fioriappslibrary.hana.ondemand.com/sap/fix/externalViewer/)
- **Fiori Launchpad** (FLP) is a Fiori App by itself, which is configurable using various methods. FLP exists for ABAP, SAP Enterprise Portal, SAP Cloud Portal, SAP Cloud Foundry and is configurable in different ways in these systems. Intent based navigation that you linked above is one of the ways in an ABAP System

  - **Custom Fiori Apps** are SAPUI5 Apps that follow the Fiori Design Guidelines, as stated by @sap-fiori-crew
  - also native mobile libraries like Fiori SDK for iOS or for Android will produce native Fiori iOS apps (or Android, respectively)
  - Some **non-ui5 Apps** like SAP Mobile Cards or Mendix Apps with Fiori Theme are considered *Fiori apps* by SAP

All in all, currently, SAP states that SAP Fiori is a *user experience* (see, e.g. [this roadmap, page 11](https://www.sap.com/products/roadmaps.cross-topics.html#pdf-asset=983e325c-c37c-0010-82c7-eda71af511fa&page=11))

From the *technical* point of view, an ui5 app must at least use the Component Paradigma to be seamlessly integrateable inside a Fiori Launchpad. 
For the rest of the answer, I’ll refer to any ui5 app that implements a Component as “Fiori App”

As for your original question, and the link you used, I don’t see any *technical* reason, why a sapui5 app, that implements a component, shouldn’t be callable using intent navigation.

You can configure a tile in FLP to call a certain Fiori App. Or to call a certain action of a semantic object. That action of that object is configured to call a Fiori App using Target Mapping. The good thing is that you can call such an action on such a semantic object from any other app without knowing which App will actually be called. This allows a customer to replace an App by changing a single target mapping rather than finding and extending all other apps that are calling the one replaced app.

Answer (score 6):

SAP UI5 is the tool (so views, controllers, databinding), but SAP Fiori Apps conform to the [SAP Fiori Design Guidelines](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/).

Answer (score 2):

SAPUI5 is a JavaScript framework like React just developed by SAP and comes with a big collection of custom controls out-of-the-box.

Fiori on the other hand is SAP´s Design Language. The SAP Fiori user experience is role-based, adaptive, simple, coherent, and delightful. See also here https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/get-started/#design-principles

Answer (score 0):

There is only one difference in sap fiori and SAPUI5..
SAP Fiori apps are standard app which is provided by sap... Just we need to configured in fiori launchpad.. Fiori application is build by using SAPUI5 only.. Thats why its saying SAPUI5..
SAPUI5 is custom app which we designed as per our requirement..

In sap fiori refrence library. There some other type application also there such as webdynpro, gui type of which can also be configured in fiori launchpad.

Answer (score 0):

**SAP UI5**

UI5 is SAP own user interface to develop web application.

UI5 is now a days is getting popular to outside of SAP to build  NON-SAP application also.

UI5 uses web technologies like HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

SAPUI5 is technology whereas Fiori is a methodology.

SAPUI5 is Hybrid app (Because of HTML5).

SAPUI5 Apps runs on multiple platforms with full capability as like native apps such us SMP.

UI5 is a framework based on MVC pattern.By using this frame work developer can easily build web application.

**SAP Fiori**

Fiori is a new user experience for SAP software . To overcome the complexity of SAP traditional GUI ,New one has been developed  which is Fiori.

Fiori focus mainly on mobility. Fiori uses SAPUI5 for frontend and it uses odata to get back end data.

Without knowing SAPUI5 knowledge fiori customization is difficult. Fiori contains all the business process in the form of Role based.Currently more than 1000 roles are created  based on business process.

Answer (score 0):

**SAPUI5**

SAPUI5 is a client side HTML 5 rendering framework by which developer can create responsive application for user.

**SAP FIORI**

SAP Fiori is a collection of standard application which is based on SAPUI5 library provided by SAP. SAP Fiori applications share some standard design guidelines and way in which these application are developed.

Answer (score 0):

SAP Fiori advocate a design principle known as 1-1-3 (“one one three”). This means each screen should be designed with a single user (or role) in mind, a single task that this user wants to accomplish, and a maximum of three levels of navigation to perform this task. 
And also other design principles like coherent, delightful, simple and responsive.

Where as a Sap Ui5 app doesn't need to follow the above mentioned design principles.

SAP webIde does provide templates for each of the application types.